# Bind slug like the first URL segment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I'm developing react app use react-router-dom. I have unusual the app behavior. The app doesn't have home page. We can go to the app use 'slug'. For example: `http://siteExample.net/my-subsite`. If `my-subsite` exist in our database We need to work with this slug.
My code snippet for routes:

```js
const App = ({ isAuth, onSetSlug, slug}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    onSetSlug(window.location.pathname.split('/')[1])
  }, [])

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <MainModal />
          <ScrollToTop>
            {!isAuth ? (
              <Switch>
                <Route path={'/:slug'} exact component={lazy(() => import('./containers/notAuth/home'))} />
                <ContentWrapper
                  container
                  component="main"
                  adaptSidebar={5}
                  adaptContent={7}
                >
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path={'/:slug/login'} exact component={lazy( () => import('./containers/notAuth/login'))} />
                    <Route path={'/:slug/signup'} exact component={lazy(() => import('./containers/notAuth/signup'))} />
                    <Redirect to={'/:slug'} />
                  </Switch>
                </ContentWrapper>
                <Redirect to={'/:slug'} />
              </Switch>
            </ScrollToTop>
          </Suspense>
        </div>
       </Router>
)}
```

There is a issue that `:slug/login` doesn't replace on `my-subsite/login` for example.By the way it's working only for my local machine. When I publish it to remote host it doesn't work completely.

Comment: remove the inner `Switch`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `exact` prop on the outer/root route since it necessarily excludes matching any subroutes.

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path={'/:slug'} // <-- want this path prefix to match
    component={lazy(() => import('./containers/notAuth/home'))}
  />
    <ContentWrapper
      container
      component="main"
      adaptSidebar={5}
      adaptContent={7}
    >
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path={'/:slug/login'}
          exact
          component={lazy( () => import('./containers/notAuth/login'))}
        />
        <Route
          path={'/:slug/signup'}
          exact
          component={lazy(() => import('./containers/notAuth/signup'))}
        />
        <Redirect to={'/:slug'} />
      </Switch>
    </ContentWrapper>
  <Redirect to={'/:slug'} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: In this case it doesn't even push me to the new screen

Comment: @WhyAlwaysMe *What* doesn't push you to the new screen? What is a new screen? Can you be more specific?